# GCP Cloud Function Error Reporting in GO not working as documented

Tags: google-cloud-platform

According to https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting#functions-errors-log-go

If my "GO" cloud function throws a panic, it should appear in the Error Reporting dashboard.

The logs are certainly capturing the panic, but I see nothing related in my Error Dashboard (in the same project)

Am I missing something here? The error dashboard is showing a few errors from other things, just not any of my cloud functions.

My code is pretty much...

```
func init() {
    functions.HTTP("DoThing", DoThing)
}

func DoThing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    panic("thing dun broke")
}
```

Comment: What did you complete to instrument your app: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/go

Answer (score 0):

It is because I needed a newer version of the github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go module. I was using 1.7.3, and in 1.7.4 they released a fix for this...

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/pull/203/commits/fb58e1e3e00ad7af3c5d4beed62437d0c54ac98b

Glad its fixed, sad it I had to chase it :(